# not able to install coffeescript

Tags: javascript, terminal, coffeescript

seems like a nifty thing to use, but it's not installing.

```
Last login: Sun Mar  9 14:14:32 on ttys001
users-Mac-Pro:~ mac$ sudo npm install -g coffee-script
Password:
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/-/mkdirp-0.3.5.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/-/mkdirp-0.3.5.tgz
/usr/local/bin/coffee -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee
/usr/local/bin/cake -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/cake
coffee-script@1.7.1 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script
└── mkdirp@0.3.5
users-Mac-Pro:~ mac$ npm install -g coffee-script
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script'
npm ERR! error rolling back  coffee-script@1.7.1 { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 3,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script' }
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 11.4.2
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "coffee-script"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/mac
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/mac/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

what's wrong? I tried installing it with and without global installs

Comment: npm Error..! you Installed node.js ?

Comment: How did you install node? brew? You shouldn't need to use `sudo`

Comment: @elclanrs: You do for a global install.